# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in /home/karencom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php on line 57

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in
> /home/karencom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
> on line 57

Below is the code

```
function wc_get_container() : \Psr\Container\ContainerInterface {
    return $GLOBALS['wc_container'];
}
```

How do I solve this, I've tried for hours to change the ":" to "{" but it returns another error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in
> /home/karencom/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce.php
> on line 57

Comment: That code looks totally fine to me - which version of PHP do you use? Also, if this is unmodified code of WooCommerce, why not ask their support for help?

Comment: Most likely you're using a lower version of PHP than the code requires. The return type declaration is only allowed since PHP 7.0

Comment: Hi Nico, I'm using PHP: 7.0, and thank you for the idea. Lemme ask the WooCommerce support.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.0, which you use according to a comment, is horribly outdated. All kinds of official support have ended more than three years ago in Dec 2018. Before blaming WooCommerce, you could update your server.

Even if you haven't told which version of WooCommerce you use, the [official document for server requirements](https://woocommerce.com/document/update-php-wordpress/) lists a minimum version of PHP 7.2.